# Equals keyword ambiguity in golang documentation

Tags: go

I am having trouble understanding the Equals keyword in this context. Could someone explain whether it is a type or a function as I am not able to find docs for golang pertaining to this. https://github.com/ory/ladon/blob/9fada03c11c183e37c13f581ee6deca8d8e747f9/condition_string_equal.go#L19-L21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struct is a user-defined type in golang having a group of fields. So in your case

```
type StringEqualCondition struct {
    Equals string `json:"equals"`
}
```

StringEqualCondition is a struct having a field named Equals.

It's just a simple variable of type string in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a keyword, is the variable (struct member, actually) name.

In `golang`, the format to declare a variable is `name type`. Thus, on that line, a member named Equals of type string is defined. The capital letter means public visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the golang documentation, Equals is not a keyword, and it's not a type *or* a function in the code that you linked; it's the name of a struct field.